# Block a user from viewing a PDF until they log in?

Tags: asp-classic

I am working on an old Classic ASP website and there is a directory that contents a handful of PDF documents. Is there a way to stop a user from accessing said pdf documents via a direct link (www.example.com/example.pdf) until they login? If so, how would I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Does ASP have the build in Membership provider which controls access with a couple lines in a web.config in that directory

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The following article from Microsft explains how to protect access to certain pages using classic ASP.

[How To Use Simple ASP Code to Password Protect Your ASP Pages](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301464)

Here are a couple of additional links, that are both for ASP.NET, but perhaps you can use the same ideas in classic ASP.

[Thread: How do I password protect a sub folder of my website, to deny anonymous access?](http://forums.iis.net/t/1041594.aspx)

Here's a similar article: [Protecting Folders with Forms Authentication](http://www.codefixer.com/asp-net/tutorials/protecting-folders-with-forms-authentication.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I presume your web site already have a login infrastructure.

If not you should add it as first thing | http://www.evolt.org/node/28652.

Then create page and put it in the place of the resource you want to protect. E.g. replace `http://youwebsite.com/dir1/dir2/file.pdf` with `http://yourwebsite.com/dir1/dir2/getfilepdf.asp`.

In your new script check if the user have done log on, if not send it back to log on page.
If the user is correctly authenticated, read the file and return it to browser with `Response.BinaryWrite`.

The web is full of samples. Read this | http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307603.

Answer (score 0):

Password protection on the page listing your documents will not prevent direct access to the documents. For example if your documents are listed by folder view or are linked from any web page then every search engine and spider on the planet already knows the document's location in your site. So here's what you can do...

Start by moving the document folder to below root level, then use FileSystemObject to deliver the document. For documents over 2-4 Mb you should deliver them in "chunks".

Now you can add a condition to your download script to verify the user's log-in status or redirect to log-in. Your comment link will now look something like:

```
http://somesite.com/load-pdf.asp?id=mydocuent.pdf
```

If you were providing a list of documents by folder view you can still do that using FileSystemObject.